# Let $A$ be $10 \times 10$ real matrix. then which of the following is correct?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, alternative-proof

Let $A$ be $10 \times 10$ real matrix. then which of the following is correct?
[$\rho(A)=Rank(A)]$

(A) $\rho(A^8)=\rho(A^9)$

(B)$\rho(A^9)=\rho(A^{10})$

(C) $\rho(A^{10})=\rho(A^{11})$

(D)$\rho(A^8)=\rho(A^7)$

(A),(B),(D) are false. since if I take an upper triangular matrix  $A$ with all zero entries in the diagonal and 1 in all $i<j$ region. Then, (A),(B),(D) are false. Hence, $C$ is the correct answer. Is there any shorter way to solve this?

Comment: Not really. The Jordan form is useful here.

Comment: How Jordan form is useful here?

Comment: The rank can be seen easily from the Jordan form (the Jordan blocks corresponding to the zero eigenvalues are the only places where the rank changes when taking powers). So, it is straightforward, by taking Jordan blocks of the appropriate size, to see that A,B,D fail. It is also straightforward to see that the rank cannot change after the $n$th power (because all Jordan blocks corresponding to zero eigenvalues will be zero at this stage).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is $v$ such that $A^{11} v = 0$ but $A^{10} v \ne 0$, then the null spaces of $A, A^2, \ldots, A^{11}$ are all distinct.  But these are nested, so their dimensions are all different. $\mathfrak N(A)$ has dimension at least $1$, ...., $\mathfrak N(A^{11})$ has dimension at least $11$, but that's impossible.

Comment: I know null spaces are nested. But I am not able to prove How these null spaces are distinct? is it followed from the fact that $A^{10}(Av)=0$ but $A^9(Av)\neq 0$. So, $\mathfrak N(A^{10})\neq\mathfrak N(A^{9})$. so, on.am I correct?

Comment: Yes, that's right.